# RxJs: distinctUntilChanged still emits duplicate values

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a stream of values that I limit using a lower and upper bound, and to decrease the amount of logging I would like to only emit values if they change. The problem is that the second `distinctUntilChanged()` in the following snippet still produces duplicates:

```
Observable // emits i.e. [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 10, 20]
.distinctUntilChanged() // becomes [2, 5, 10, 20]
.map(target => {
  const correctedTarget = Math.min(Math.max(target, MINIMUM), MAXIMUM); // Let's say min: 5, max: 10
  if(correctedTarget != target) {
    logger.warn(`Prediction wants to scale out-of-bounds to ${target}, limiting to ${correctedTarget}`);
  }
  return correctedTarget;
}) // becomes [5, 5, 10, 10]
.distinctUntilChanged() // should be [5, 10], but is [5, 5, 10, 10]
```

The RxJs docs state that the filter defaults to a simple equality comparison, so I'd expect that this should Just Work™.

Comment: You're completely sure your values come in in order? I took your code and ran it against rxjs 4 and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, i added `.do(val => { logger.debug(value); })` both before and after the last line, can confirm that it keeps emitting the same value.

Comment: Ok. Can you please post complete sample code that exhibits this problem? Can you please also post which version of rxjs you're using? As I said, the quick sample conversion I ran worked correctly.

Comment: I'm using rxjs v4.1.0. Tried an MWE which actually works as expected, as you said. It looks like there is a problem on my end. I tried manually passing a comparator function that logs both values to see what happens, but that never gets called for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues (once again) identified the problem (also thanks for the help [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855065/matt-burnell)). It turns out that the initial assumption was wrong - the outline of the code was as follows:

```
Observable // emits credentials on some interval
.flatmap(credentials => {
  return Observable2.doSomething()
         .distinctUntilChanged()
         ...
})
```

As you can see, the `distinctUntilChanged` was chained to `Observable2`, which is a new observable stream every time the credentials get emitted. This also explains why the comparator function I made doesn't get called at all: there is just one value every time so there is nothing to compare to.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this here because this question was a top match for 'duplicate values'.

This following was emitting duplicate values for me.

#### BAD - Emits the time continuously! Crashes browser!

The intent here is to output the `getCurrentTime()` value of a YouTube video.

```
this.currentTime = this.timer.pipe(
    filter(i => this.isReady),
    map(i => this.ytPlayer.getCurrentTime(), distinctUntilChanged())
);
```

#### GOOD - Returns distinct values

```
this.currentTime = this.timer.pipe(
    filter(i => this.isReady),
    map(i => this.ytPlayer.getCurrentTime()),
    distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

I'll leave it to the reader to spot the difference. Note that these both *did* compile with typescript.

Comment: this doesn't help to explain why the difference matters

Comment: @bing this was a case of misplaced parenthesis - the distinctuntilchanged is literally never called because it’s not even in the pipe. It’s actually part of the expression inside the Map call. This was so confusing to me at the time which is why I posted it here. Probably long overdue an explanation.